# Jquery select next class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

What I am trying to do is to add a find in page functionality to a webpage I am working on. And I am using the [Highlight plugin](http://bartaz.github.io/sandbox.js/jquery.highlight.html) to highlight the search term. You can see a basic demo version on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lm46Lz4t/).

Highlight plugin adds a span with class "highlight". I want to scroll to each "highlight" class when you press "Find" button repeatedly. What is the best and easy way to do this? I tried next() but couldn't get it to work.

```
function findText(str){
        searchTerm = str;
        $(".col-xs-8").unhighlight();
        $(".col-xs-8").highlight(str);
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(".highlight").offset().top
        }, 100);
      }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/chakrei/gwx130tt/) fiddle.

I have added the below code and I have made few changes in CSS as well. Has this solved your prob??

```
 function findText(str){          
    searchTerm = str;
    $(".col-xs-8").unhighlight();
    $(".col-xs-8").highlight(str);
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".highlight").eq($('.hide').val()).offset().top
    }, 100);          
      $('.hide').val(parseInt($('.hide').val())+1);
  }
```

Comment: I noticed that when you search for something and then search for another word the .hide class value doesn't reset so it messes up the scrolling for following searches. I made little bit of changes to the js and you can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/o13vongn/2/
Is there a more easier/efficient way of doing this?